# How to scale bitmaps based on device screen size in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to create images with sizes relevant to the size of the screen they are on. Basically I have a scaled bitmap `50w * 50h`. I want it to be `50w * 50h` on a small device, slightly larger on a larger device, etc... Is there anyway to make a scaled bitmap relevant to the screen size it's on. I have that of making a `dimen.xml` file with different `dp` values for different screen width's. But it seems so demanding. Is there any easier way to do it? I have done some research but found nothing, can anyone help?

Comment: That literally had nothing to do with what I asked. Like nothing. I know how to create a scaled bitmap. Not what im asking

Answer (score -1):

May be [this](https://gist.github.com/nesquena/3885707fd3773c09f1bb):

```
 public class BitmapScaler {
     // scale and keep aspect ratio
     public static Bitmap scaleToFitWidth(Bitmap b, int width) {
         float factor = width / (float) b.getWidth();
         return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, (int) (b.getHeight() * factor), true);
     }


     // scale and keep aspect ratio
     public static Bitmap scaleToFitHeight(Bitmap b, int height) {
        float factor = height / (float) b.getHeight();
         return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) (b.getWidth() * factor), height, true);
     }


     // scale and keep aspect ratio
     public static Bitmap scaleToFill(Bitmap b, int width, int height) {
         float factorH = height / (float) b.getHeight();
         float factorW = width / (float) b.getWidth();
         float factorToUse = (factorH > factorW) ? factorW : factorH;
         return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) (b.getWidth() * factorToUse), 
         (int) (b.getHeight() * factorToUse), true);
      }


     // scale and don't keep aspect ratio
     public static Bitmap strechToFill(Bitmap b, int width, int height) {
         float factorH = height / (float) b.getHeight();
         float factorW = width / (float) b.getWidth();
         return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) (b.getWidth() * factorW), 
         (int) (b.getHeight() * factorH), true);
     }
 }
```

or [this](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Working-with-the-ImageView) will help you.

Comment: scaleToFill has a typo that needs to be fixed

Comment: what typo do you mean??

Comment: should be `float factorH = height / (float) b.getHeight();`

I submitted an edit